# Can I develop Java programs if I have only JRE installed?

Tags: java

I have JRE 1.7 installed on my system. Due to some admin issues I don't have JDK on my system. is there any way I can develop Java programs with JRE only?

Comment: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: I think Eclipse can run with only a JRE because it has it's own compiler that does not depend on the JDK (I don't use Eclipse, so I can't be certain)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It does.

Comment: Ecj, jikes or gcj. Or javac from the JDK.

Comment: Why not a bundle of portable languages that includes open jdk see http://simpll.info. Note : I created this. Only  for  Windows. Extract the archive and use the jdk.

Answer (score 17):

### *No you can't develop java programs only with JRE*

You will need `JDK` for compiling your programs.`JRE` provides only runtime environment,but `JDK` is something you will need to compile your code to make them executable by your `JRE`.You will need `javac` for compiling your code which is present in `JDK`.

[image]

However for resolving the issue of admin rights you are having, you can download and install **eclipse** which has its own built in compiler.

Comment: Wrong. See various answers here mentioning Eclipse with JRE only.

Comment: @icza in this case installing Eclipse is equal to installing JDK. Pure JRE does not allow to compile applications. And just for information, do not use `wrong` word in conversations, it is kinda rude. It is better to say that you have different opinion.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov The difference is Eclispe **does not** require being installed. It's a zip file which you can extract in your home folder. The question stated he/she does not have admin rights to install the JDK, but admin rights are not required to extrat a zip file and start Eclipse.

Comment: @icza yes, also there are portable JDK packages. And they do not need to be `installed`, but just unzipped.

Comment: @icza as Rafael Osipov is depicting that installing Eclipse is equal to installing JDK.and also the OP is asking to develop java programs using **only JRE**,which I believe is not possible on this Earth.

Comment: @nobalG Yes, while it is true that with only JRE you can't develop Java applications, the reason it was asked is because there is no admin rights to install JDK - but that is not neccessarily the only way to overcome the need to compile the Java sources. The goal of the questioner can be achieved still without having JDK to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need some program which compiles your sources, but that **doesn't neccessarily have to be the JDK.**

For example you can download Eclipse which only requires a JRE, it has it's own compiler (built-in) and you can develop with that. Eclipse does not require any admin priviliges, it's a zip file which you can download and extract.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile them in order to develop and that is why you need jdk

Answer (score 1):

You can't develop any `Java` application since you need `JDK(Java Development Kit)` to compile your code. `JRE(Java Runtime Environment)` provides run time environment only. You can run your compiled code in `JRE`.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is somehow "yes,but..."

java source code execution procedure is split into 2 steps :

1)compiling the source code into a byte-code,thus generating the .class file

2)interpreting the VM specific instructions from the .class file into native instructions

.java----javac---->.class----java---->native code

needless to mention that the "javac" , the compiler of the java source code is  in not part of the JRE!

so in order to develop java programs without JDK you have to skip the first step and keep using  exclusively the "java" tool,thus dealing directly with byte-code !

in some extent and if you're acquainted with the JVM internals,it's possible to write some lines of byte-code using hex or text editors and then running the .class file;but you will not go further then that specially when it comes to creating complex applications as this require super-human capabilities :that's  a highly daunting task .

nevertheless,todays java frameworks almost all use direct byte-code manipulation and tools like the **asm** framework or **javassit**

javassist does not require the JDK and you can generate a class from scratch and then compile/run it

> java -classpath .:javassist-x.x.jar test "some arguments"

(no need to compile classes)

but again,that is only for restricted use and in order to develop java applications you have to use some JDK...
finally,you have to strive to acquire full control upon what is running in you machine;recent frameworks are resource-greedy and needs a huge amount of resources(disk space,memory...) and many tools and framworks require full control,i mean administrator right : for instance i remember that once a time  borland delphi refused to start and i  had to give it full access rights to start...

Answer (score 1):

I request you to resolve admin rights. Else I have two options for you.

1) You cannot do anything without Java Development Kit.[image: Hope this diagram makes why its not possible]

2)You can install a IDE to code Java which makes your work in the current situation simpler. Use Eclipse or NetBeans. I would recommend Eclipse to you anyway. You can download eclipse from this link https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Try downloading JDK from this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index-jsp-138218.html.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

JDK is needed to compile your java file into class file. And JRE will execute the generated class file and provides the output.
If you have admin problems in your m/c then you can install the JDK in some other m/c and take the class files into your system and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) includes its own compiler and doesn't depend on the JDK compiler. But indeed, the JRE is just the runtime environment and doesn't include the compiler or other development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this to do you job or not?  If it's your job, you should have access or they should install it.  If you don't have access because it's not your job, I suggest installing the JDK at home (or on a laptop you can take with you)

> Due to some admin issues I don't have JDK on my system.

Install it in your home directory or another directory you can write to.  Your admins can't prevent you from installing the JDK if you have enough disk space.

Answer (score 0):

JRE is not just sufficient, without compiling the code for that you need Jdk which have compiler to compile the code.