# Eclipse for C++ (Mac OSX): Do I need JRE or JDK?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I have no idea what's what. I'm simply trying to install Eclipse on my computer so that I can take an intro to computer science course which uses C++. I really have no idea whether or not I should download a JRE or JDK (I've read the descriptions on the Oracle's website, but I'm still not sure).

Can someone please provide some help?

BTW: I'm trying to download a JRE or JDK b/c when I start Eclipse, it says that the current version of the JVM isn't suitable and requires version 1.7 or greater.

Comment: I think you only *need* the JRE for Eclipse, strictly speaking, since Eclipse has its own compiler. But there's not really a reason not to get the JDK (which includes the JRE, plus the source code for a lot of the Java standard library, plus the official compiler for Java, plus some other tools and useful stuff)

Comment: [SEE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24751065/681929)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Development Kit (JDK) is only needed if you intend to develop Java applications, because it contains both `javac`, a Java compiler (along with some other tools) and a runtime environment to run compiled Java code. On the contrary, Java Runtime Environment (JRE) only contains a virtual machine (runtime environment) and thus using it you can only run Java code, not compile it. Because Eclipse is itself written in Java, you need a JRE to run.

Bottom line: since you intend to developer C++ and not Java applications you need only to download JRE. This will save you some disk space (since JDK is obviously larger).

Answer (score 0):

1.Download JDK and install it.You can use following link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

2.Setup JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.

On windows:

- Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select
  Properties.
- Click the Advanced tab.
- Click the Environment Variables button.
- Under System Variables, click New.
- Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
- Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java
  Development Kit.
- **add** :$JAVA_HOME/bin to the PATH variable

On linux:

- export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
- export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

hope this helps.

Comment: why JDK? the OP need to run Eclipse to develop non-Java code, hence JRE is sufficient.