# How Eclipse work with and without JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse for Java installed on my 64-bit Windows 10. And since than, I was able to do Java development without any configuration.

Previously, the automatically build is selected by default. But when I manually delete the .class files, and want to build again, nothing happens.
When I try to run the program, it was not surprised that the error message says that it cannot find the class files.

Notice that, from the beginning, I didn't configure JDK in Eclipse, and it worked. 
I found some source on stack overflow that says, Eclipse has its built-in compiler such that it does not need the javac in JDK.

[Can I develop Java programs if I have only JRE installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751032/can-i-develop-java-programs-if-i-have-only-jre-installed/24751065)

But why after I deleted the .class files, the built-in compiler does not work ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Regarding the JDK: if you are using Eclipse, then you don't need JDK because eclipse has it's own compiler. However for some plugins like Maven to work JDK will be required.
2. Regarding building the project: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? 
   Clean command is available under Project tab.