# Eclipse running with just JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I am using Eclipse to build and run java web application(with Tomcat).
If i go to

`Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JRE`

i note that i have just one "`JRE`" configured.

My question is :
If i only have one JRE configured , how is it possible to Eclipse compile my application ? everything compile and runs smoothly but how is it possible ?
`Jre` is just the `JVM` , does not have the compiler i guess

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler built-in and doesn't use javac.

Comment: Check this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751032/can-i-develop-java-programs-if-i-have-only-jre-installed/24751065

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061654/2670892